# Definition mx.binding:BindingManager could not be found

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, osmf

Why I'm getting this error in a actionscript project using flash Builder?

I'm not even embedding anything, I'm just extending an OSMF class 'NetStreamLoadTrait' which has some metadata, that's it. [ExcludeClass]

I'm using another OSMF project insted the one coming with the Flex SDK 4.0, but I have deleted the osmf package inside the SDK ( using the Actionscript Build Path )

This is so frustating...

Comment: Do you have a line number with your error, can you identify in which part of your app , in which class the error is happening? Can you use breakpoints to try & identify at what stage the error happens? With Flash Builder , there's a lot you can do , to try and locate where the error is happening. Try do to that, it'll help you being more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ActionScript project won't have the Flex Framework as a library in the build path.  It sounds like you're trying to use a class which tries to access the Flex Framework's Binding Manager.  But, it's hard to tell w/o seeing code / testing the project.

Comment: It has in the new version of Flash Builder, it's the only way to access to classes like Sprite. If I remove the SDK, i cannot call it. Take into account that having the SDK in the actionscript project doesn't increase the size of the actionscript project.

Comment: That is a surprise to me; but it is beyond my usual use cases, so I don't have a specific answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check in the variables definition if you have the [Bindable] statement. It is a Flex issue and then remove it, in order to exclude it from the as3 data flow.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by [Bindable] metatag. In my case I did not have any mx or spark flex imports, but I just had the Bindable metatag which caused the problem